# Nil Value Error in Love2D while using StateMachine

Tags: lua, lua-table

I want to call a "Entity:changeState" by using "self.player:changeState()" but the function is not responding. I've highlighted the problem using comment please go through it.
I tried debugging the problem but the trail got vanish in "self.player:changeState()", IDk why it's not calling the function and giving me nil value.

Note: I type my code in different files(eg - PlayState.lua)

ScreenShot result using Debugger https://imgur.com/a/HmmnuPh

```
-- PlayState.lua
-- Class library [https://github.com/vrld/hump/blob/master/class.lua][1]
PlayState = Class{}

function PlayState:init()
    self.background = math.random(3)

    self.player = Player({
        texture = 'green-alien',
        characterX = 10,
        characterY = 10,
        stateMachine = StateMachine {
            ['idle'] = function() return PlayerIdleState(self.player) end
        }
    })
    
    self.player:changeState('idle') --giving me error here
end
```

```
-- Player.lua
Player = Class{__includes = Entity}

function Player:init(def)
    Entity.init(self, def)
end

function Player:update(dt)
    Entity.update(self, dt)
end

function Player:render()
    Entity.render(self)
end
```

```
-- Entity.lua
Entity = Class{}

function Entity:init(def)
    self.characterX = def.characterX
    self.characterY = def.characterY
    self.texture = def.texture

    self.stateMachine = def.stateMachine -- [[Already checked by debugging here the argument 
                                            passed successfully refer screenshot]]

end

function Entity:changeState(state)
    self.stateMachine:change(state) -- The function that I want to call
end
```

```
-- StateMachine.lua
-- if everything goes well the value will end up here.
StateMachine = Class{}

function StateMachine:init(states)
    self.empty = {
        render = function() end,
        update = function() end,
        enter = function() end,
        exit = function() end
    }
    self.states = states or {} -- [name] -> [function that returns states]
    self.current = self.empty
end

function StateMachine:change(stateName, enterParams)
    assert(self.states[stateName]) -- state must exist!
    self.current:exit()
    self.current = self.states[stateName]()
    self.current:enter(enterParams)
end

function StateMachine:update(dt)
    self.current:update(dt)
end

function StateMachine:render()
    self.current:render()
end
```

This is the error I got

```
Error

src/states/game/PlayState.lua:15: attempt to call method 'changeState' (a nil value)


Traceback

src/states/game/PlayState.lua:15: in function 'init'
lib/class.lua:79: in function <lib/class.lua:77>
src/StateMachine.lua:17: in function 'change'
src/states/game/StartState.lua:13: in function 'update'
src/StateMachine.lua:22: in function 'update'
main.lua:45: in function 'update'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

Comment: I think you should define `Player:changeState`.

Comment: Please add a link to your class library. That `Class` function looks like it's doing weird things.

Comment: Added Class Library.

Comment: I've tried `Player:changeState` got same error.

Comment: You're using a lot of global variables for modules that could be stored in locals. I bet `Entity` is nil when you do `Player = Class{__includes = Entity}`.

Comment: should I remove the `__includes = Entity`? if yes, then I already did but the situation is same.

Comment: No, you should ensure that `Entity` is not nil there. Even better, you should make a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see for ourselves what the problem might be.

Comment: I've attach some screenshot by disabling some function -working code  
https://imgur.com/a/MkwDRTg

and again I've enabled those function Error Code - https://imgur.com/a/i78qBvO

Answer (score 0):

I've rewrite the same code again from scratch and it worked. Maybe the problem was in the capitalization of letters.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).